Replacing electric baseboards
We just bought a house that use electric baseboards for heating. The house is a split level with a half basement and kind of a half second floor. It also has Central AC so some duct work is already there. I think there is gas line too as it has a gas water heater. We live in Northern Virginia and winter can get to close to freezing for a short time. I’m thinking about switching the electric baseboards system for something else with less electricity consumption. We will get an expert in to get quote once we can enter the house but I would like a ballpark estimate. What would be the options for heating and how much would it cost to convert from electric baseboards?

Costs are generally NOT discussed here. They vary by state/country/region, change over time as new technologies are introduced and also vary a lot depending on many details.
Electric resistance heat is the most expensive common way to heat a house, at least in the US. Your main alternatives are:
Forced air natural gas furnace.
This is extremely common in Northern Virginia (I'm on the other side of Washington, DC in suburban Maryland). Not recommended these days if you have to add natural gas to your house, but you already have that for your water heater so it should be relatively easy. However, I don't think it will generally be practical to add a furnace into an existing air-conditioning air handler, in which case you will need to replace the air handler with an actual furnace, which can then have the air conditioning coil installed inside it. Whether that is practical and/or cost-effective compared to an entire new heating and air conditioning system will depend on your HVAC installer. Note that both a gas furnace (because "gas") and an air conditioner (because "refrigerant") require special skills to install and are generally not DIY projects.
Heat Pump
A heat pump is essentially an air conditioner that can "reverse" to heat as well as cool. Modern heat pumps are much more effective at low temperatures than they were a few decades ago. Plus you don't even need a backup heating system for super-cold days because you already have the reliable (but expensive to run) baseboard heaters. The problem is that generally an air conditioner can't be turned into a heat pump (even though conceptually it should be very easy). Which means again likely replacing the air conditioner to make it all work.
If your air conditioner is only a few years old then replacement may not be worth it right now. On the other hand, if it is more than 10 years old then replacement may be worthwhile (whether you go with a gas furnace + A/C or a heat pump) because new air conditioners (and heat pumps) are much more efficient than older models.
Which way to go? The key factors are cost and your feelings about burning fossil fuels. What I recommend is getting a few estimates and then estimate total cost of ownership:

Installation Cost
Estimated yearly running cost based on average temperatures and current gas and electricity costs
Estimated system lifetime (typically 15 to 20 years)

I did an analysis recently for a water heater (a bit simpler than HVAC) and found that it was pretty much the same for gas (lower initial cost) vs. heat pump (lower running cost) but both of those were far lower than resistance electric (lower initial cost but way higher running cost). HVAC is a little more complex, but assuming you expect to live in your house for many years, TCO is what matters.
